# TemplateDoesNotExist at /hello/ Django error

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner at django python. I am getting an above error although I am having my template a correct directory.

My view.py is like this.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
def hello(request):
    return render(request,"C:/Users/Vivek/myproject/myapp/template/hello.html",{})
```

I am having hello.html at C:\Users\Vivek\myproject\myapp\template

Below is the error I am getting.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /hello/
C:/Users/Vivek/myproject/myapp/template/hello.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/
Django Version: 1.11.10
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
C:/Users/Vivek/myproject/myapp/template/hello.html
```

Comment: I would advice you to use os.path.sep to check whether forward slash or backward slash is used as path separator. Windows uses backward slashes. I guess you should change your HTML path with the right separator.

Comment: You need to give relative path of the template e.g. `'hello.html'` with respect to template directories you have added.

Comment: actually i even tried that, but i got this error.

This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection

Comment: @Rohan after that I got this error. IOError at /hello/
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: u'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\contrib\\admin\\templates\\myapp\template\\hello.html'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/
Django Version: 1.11.10
Exception Type: IOError

I changed the path to return render(request,"myapp\template\hello.html",{})

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad way to link your template.
Instead check your settings file and define OS absolute path.
It will look something like this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Change your code from

```
return render(request,"C:/Users/Vivek/myproject/myapp/template/hello.html",{})
```

To this

```
return render(request,"hello.html",{})
```

It should work.

Answer (score 2):

The Django way of doing this is to define the directory for templates in your settings file

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Hence, just add this line to your TEMPLATES setting and then you are good to go.

Django automatically searches templates in the directories you pass and you just need to give template name in the render method.